# Docker container cannot run on port 3000 despite no process using it

Tags: docker

```
Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:3000 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3000: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
```

However, running `netstat -ano | findstr 3000` doesn't show anything using this port. So why cannot it be used by a container ?

Edit : I hate Stackoverflow. If I go to a "duplicate" question to say that none of the solutions worked, that's a bad thing. If I make a new question, that's a bad thing. What am I supposed to do then ??

Comment: The error message suggests that it's a permission problem. Not that something is already using the port.